# CreatePalette producing two palettes

Tags: front-end, palettes

```
f := CreatePalette[PasteButton[α]];

f
```

Evaluating `f` will generate two palettes and this is not expected. Before version 10, I always get one.

Is this a possible bug? Or something change in this behavior?

I'm on windows 8.1 x64 and v10.0.1.

---

A friend told me

```
f[] := CreatePalette[PasteButton[α]];
```

will generate only one palette. The problem is I must type `[]` each time I call this palette.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This only happens if you have the **Suggestions Bar** enabled.  *Turn that damn thing off already!*  It is the source of unending grief.

(Problem confirmed in 10.0.2 under Windows.)